# To install GNU time in OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, time

BSD time gives this kind of output

```
9990

real    0m4.371s
user    0m1.548s
sys 0m2.167s
```

GNU time gives then again this kind of output

```
9990
1.56s user 1.46s system 82% cpu 3.648 total
```

Brew search gtime gives nothing. 
GNU time is probably in some C library, however, I am not sure which. 
There is no apparent package for it.

How can you install GNU time in OSX?

Comment: Using /usr/bin/time gives me the results that you want. time by itself with a command is a shell keyword.

Comment: @fd0 I do not get such an output. My time is also in `usr/bin/time`. My time version is BSD 1993. You must have different version of time.

Comment: `time date` vs `/usr/bin/time date` produce 2 different outputs (like your examples above). But `which time` gives /usr/bin/time.

Comment: brew install gnu-time

Comment: @Masi the time man page states BSD June 6, 1993. I have no idea why your results are different.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is available as...

```sh
brew install gnu-time
```

Which you can then call as...

```sh
gtime ...
```

Comment: you just beat me to it. https://gist.github.com/gregelin/9529716

Comment: No manuals installed by this in `gtime`. How can you get manuals also with this command? I would like to get more significant numbers in timing.

Comment: The original package from GNU doesn't appear to have a man page. However it does have an info file you can find with `info time`.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 [here's an online version of the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)

Comment: If you want to call it as `time`, then install it as `brew install gnu-time --with-default-names`. Your original installation of bsd-time will still exist, but gnu-time will be executed by default as it appears in your PATH first.

Answer (score 2):

GNU time is available in [homebrew](http://brew.sh) in package [gnu-time](http://braumeister.org/formula/gnu-time).